# How to rename files in zip archive without extracting and recompressing them?

Tags: linux, bash

I need to rename all the files on a zip file from `AAAAA-filename.txt` to `BBBBB-filename.txt`, and I want to know if I can automate this task without having to extract all files, rename and then zip again. Unzipping one at a time, renaming and zipping again is acceptable.

What I have now is:

```
for file in *.zip
do
    unzip $file
    rename_txt_files.sh
    zip *.txt $file
done;
```

But I don't know if there is a fancier version of this where I don't have to use all that extra disk space.

Comment: Use the rename capability of zipnote?  http://www.computerhope.com/unix/zipnote.htm

Comment: I don't have permissions to install software in the machine where I need to do this @bishop.

Comment: Well, create a mapping between old name and new name, then iterate over that mapping. If the old name exists in the archive, extract it from the archive to disk, rename on disk, add newly renamed to archive. If all that succeeds, remove the old name from the archive.  Can be done in bash, but I find bash arrays to be cumbersome, so I might fallback on a P* language.

Comment: Please show your coding efforts.

Comment: @Cyrus I currently have a working solution but I would like to know if this can be done without extracting all the files.

Comment: @Topo if you have python on the host, I have a better solution.

Comment: @Massimo I do have python on the host so feel free to try to provide a better solution.

Answer (score 5):

7z have command `rn` to rename:

> 7z rn arr.zip old new

Answer (score 1):

**plan**

> - find offsets of filenames with strings
> - use dd to overwrite new names ( note will only work with same filename lengths ). otherwise would also have to find and overwrite
>     the filenamelength field..

backup your zipfile before trying this

**zip_rename.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

strings -t d test.zip | \
grep '^\s\+[[:digit:]]\+\sAAAAA-\w\+\.txt' | \
sed 's/^\s\+\([[:digit:]]\+\)\s\(AAAAA\)\(-\w\+\.txt\).*$/\1 \2\3 BBBBB\3/g' | \
while read -a line; do
  line_nbr=${line[0]};
  fname=${line[1]};
  new_name=${line[2]};
  len=${#fname};
#  printf "line: "$line_nbr"\nfile: "$fname"\nnew_name: "$new_name"\nlen: "$len"\n";
  dd if=<(printf $new_name"\n") of=test.zip bs=1 seek=$line_nbr count=$len conv=notrunc  
done;
```

**output**

```
$ ls
AAAAA-apple.txt  AAAAA-orange.txt  zip_rename.sh
$ zip test.zip AAAAA-apple.txt AAAAA-orange.txt 
  adding: AAAAA-apple.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: AAAAA-orange.txt (stored 0%)
$ ls
AAAAA-apple.txt  AAAAA-orange.txt  test.zip  zip_rename.sh
$ ./zip_rename.sh 
15+0 records in
15+0 records out
15 bytes (15 B) copied, 0.000107971 s, 139 kB/s
16+0 records in
16+0 records out
16 bytes (16 B) copied, 0.000109581 s, 146 kB/s
15+0 records in
15+0 records out
15 bytes (15 B) copied, 0.000150529 s, 99.6 kB/s
16+0 records in
16+0 records out
16 bytes (16 B) copied, 0.000101685 s, 157 kB/s
$ unzip test.zip 
Archive:  test.zip
 extracting: BBBBB-apple.txt         
 extracting: BBBBB-orange.txt        
$ ls
AAAAA-apple.txt   BBBBB-apple.txt   test.zip
AAAAA-orange.txt  BBBBB-orange.txt  zip_rename.sh
$ diff -qs AAAAA-apple.txt BBBBB-apple.txt 
Files AAAAA-apple.txt and BBBBB-apple.txt are identical
$ diff -qs AAAAA-orange.txt BBBBB-orange.txt 
Files AAAAA-orange.txt and BBBBB-orange.txt are identical
```

Comment: WARINIG side effects: it can update also comments and file contents, if the files are stored not compressed.

Comment: Since the directory of a ZIP file is at the end of the file, it should be possible to edit the directory only, and not expose the file contents to any changes. This would be beyond the scope of a cli script.

Answer (score -2):

We used python to

1. Extract `xyz.zip` file to `xyz_renamed/` folder
2. Rename the desired files (we are only renaming jpeg and png images) in `renameFile` function (we are changing names to lower)
3. Package the renamed contents again in `xyz_renamed.zip`
4. Delete the `xyz_renamed/` folder and `xyz.zip` file
5. Renaming `xyz_renamed.zip` to `xyz.zip`

```
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile
import shutil

# rename the individual file and return the absolute path of the renamed file
def renameFile(root, fileName):
    toks = fileName.split('.')
    newName = toks[0].lower()+'.'+toks[1]
    renamedPath =  os.path.join(root,newName)
    os.rename(os.path.join(root,fileName),renamedPath)
    return renamedPath

def renameFilesInZip(filename):
    # Create <filename_without_extension>_renamed folder to extract contents into
    head, tail = os.path.split(filename)
    newFolder = tail.split('.')[0]
    newFolder += '_renamed'
    newpath = os.path.join(head, newFolder)
    if(not os.path.exists(newpath)):
        os.mkdir(newpath)

    # extracting contents into newly created folder
    print("Extracting files\n")
    try:
        with ZipFile(filename, 'r', allowZip64=True) as zip_ref:
            zip_ref.extractall(newpath)
        zip_ref.close()
    except ResponseError as err:
        print(err)
        return -1

    # track the files that need to be repackaged in the zip with renamed files
    filesToPackage = []

    for r, d, f in os.walk(newpath):
        for item in f:
            # filter the file types that need to be renamed
            if item.lower().endswith(('.jpg', '.png')):
                # renaming file
                renamedPath = renameFile(r, item)
                filesToPackage.append(renamedPath)
            else:
                filesToPackage.append(os.path.join(r,item))


    # creating new zip file
    print("Writing renamed file\n")

    zipObj = ZipFile(os.path.join(head, newFolder)+'.zip', 'w', allowZip64 = True)
    for file in filesToPackage:
        zipObj.write(file, os.path.relpath(file, newpath))
    zipObj.close()

    # removing extracted contents and origianl zip file
    print('Cleaning up \n')
    shutil.rmtree(newpath)
    os.remove(filename)

    # renaming zipfile with renamed contents to original zipfile name
    os.rename(os.path.join(head, newFolder)+'.zip', filename)
```

Use the following code to invoke the renaming function for multiple zip files

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # zipfiles with contents to be renamed
    zipFiles = ['/usr/app/data/mydata.zip', '/usr/app/data/mydata2.zip']
    
    # do the renaming for all files one by one
    for _zip in zipFiles:
        renameFilesInZip(_zip)
```